# Laravel how to display validation errors messages to the user

Tags: laravel

In Laravel validation it just returns the errors like this

[image: The Error]

I need to display user friendly errors

the function

```
public function handleRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100|min:3',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|regex:/^01[0125][0-9]{8}$/',
        'password' => 'required|string|max:100|min:8'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('errorForm', $validator->errors()->getMessages())
            ->withInput();
    }

    try {
        User::create(['name' => $request->name, 'email' => $request->email, 'phone' => $request->phone, 'password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('success', 'Created successfully!');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->with('error', 'Error during the creation!');
    }

    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: latest version laravel

Comment: How do you display them in your blade?

Comment: simply use JQuery validator instead

Comment: @groovy_guy No! You should always have server side validation. If i disable js, i can bypass your client side validation (or I can tamper the post data).

Comment: @groovy_guy Never trust the client. Always use server-side validation!

Comment: @GertB. brombeer yeah, I never thought of that before, Thanks for the info :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments, there are a few things I would like to point out as I learned in my previous experience as software developer.

As stated in the comments there is one vital rule in programming: **Never trust the client!**

You can learn more about that [here](https://medium.com/@berniedurfee/never-trust-a-client-not-even-your-own-2de342723674).

This means that is a good habit to always use server-side validation.

Furthermore I think [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#working-with-error-messages) will help you out the most.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).